# When do Microsoft Windows Server registry settings like HKLM..SCHANNEL... take effect

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2019

When do Microsoft Windows Server registry settings such as these take effect - first boot? As soon as imported?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers]
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 128/128]
    "Enabled"=dword:00000000
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 40/128]
    "Enabled"=dword:00000000
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 56/128]
    "Enabled"=dword:00000000
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 64/128]
    "Enabled"=dword:00000000
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\Triple DES 168]
    "Enabled"=dword:00000000
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols]
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0]
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server]
    "Enabled"=dword:00000000
    "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0]
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server]
    "Enabled"=dword:00000000
    "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0]
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client]
    "Enabled"=dword:00000000
    "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server]
    "Enabled"=dword:00000000
    "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1]
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client]
    "Enabled"=dword:00000000
    "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
    
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server]
    "Enabled"=dword:00000000
    "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: What are you trying to solve? [X-AND-Y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: True enough! But sometimes, a questioner actually needs the answer for the question they asked.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, these **registry settings are immediate** - **no reboot** or anything else needed after using RegEdit, on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter. Perhaps an application restart might have been be required if a standalone application was used, however, I did not need to restart IIS or any App Pools to fix my websites.

Comment: nope, the right answer would be it depends, most values are beeing affected instantly, but some one if you restart the application and some only while a system reboot is required